# Bayesian Network: Scoring functions for structure learning?

Tags: bayesian-network, scoring-rules

Which are the widely used scoring functions for structural learning? More, specifically I am interested in scoring function that favours the random variables which have binary possible states.

For an example like:

A) Bayesian scoring function:
 - BD
 - BDe
 - BDeu
 - K2

B) Information theoretic function:
 - LL
 - MDL/BIC
 - AIC
 - NML
 - MIT

Or SparsityBoost scoring function

Comment: You mean like the [Ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Ising_model)?

Comment: I am newbie in BN so I dont know how to apply the Ising model or how would it help in computing scoring functions for a possible BN structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.157.3919&rep=rep1&type=pdf) answers your question.

In summary there are two subgroups: **i.** Bayesian functions and **ii.** Information theoretic functions (Log-likelihood based, which apply to any generative model, not just BN's).

Bear in mind that some of the scoring functions they list under **i.** are theoretical, and cannot be used (in practice) without simplifying assumptions. I think it will be clear when you read the paper.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the input. I was also looking for more inputs as how one would leverage the case that random variables are binary while evaluating the scoring functions

Comment: @skn, Sorry, I am not clear on this. Can you explain a bit more: `more inputs as how one would leverage the case that random variables are binary`. None of the scores should have a problem with binary (or in general categorical) variables. A binary variable in your BN would follow a binomial distribution and for each structure, the routines learn the parameters (as well as the structures). Learning the parameters refers to learning the Conditional Probability Tables (CPTs).